# erb unless gives inconsistent results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am seeing something unexpected and I can't explain.

I have the following code:

```
<% unless task.complete %>
... do stuff ...
<% end %>
```

This works as expected to display task obejcts that are not complete belonging to a parent object. However in one, and only one case it does not. In the case that it doesn't work the following error is thrown:

```
undefined method `encoding' for 1:Fixnum

Extracted source (around line #1):

1 <% unless task.complete %> 
2
3
4
```

The code consistently works all the time but the one case. The failure case is when one specific parent object is being presented. The parent object is unremarkable. It has tasks, both complete and not. But so do other parent objects however only one parent object produces the error.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Adding full details from logs.

```
    SELECT "engineers".* FROM "engineers" WHERE "engineers"."id" = ? ORDER BY "engineers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered tasks/_task.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered engineers/show.html.erb within layouts/application (7.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `encoding' for 1:Fixnum):
    1: <% unless task.complete %>
    2:  <div class="panel panel-default">
    3:      <div class="panel-body">
    4:          <% case task.priority
  app/views/tasks/_task.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_tasks__task_html_erb__2551940590140316489_25250680'
  app/views/engineers/show.html.erb:48:in `_app_views_engineers_show_html_erb__2573349182138661268_27996040'


  Rendered /home/local/ANT/eppreece/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /home/local/ANT/eppreece/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home/local/ANT/eppreece/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (7.3ms)
```

Comment: Check your logs for the stack trace and identify the line of code where the error is actually being thrown.

Comment: @EricP What is `complete`? Is it a method that you defined. Please share the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. @Kirti Thorat - complete is a binary column in the task table of my db. IN the db tasks belong to a parent object 'engineer'. The code executes for all engineers except one. If a task is complete I do not execute the code. The relevant code I already posted. The code within the 'unless' statement is just some html mark up which eecutes perfectly for all but one 'engineer'.

Comment: Please include the stack trace in your question for clearer formatting as well as future people reading the question.

Comment: A binary column? Was it mapped in Rails as a boolean?

Comment: @DaveNewton I used boolean because it is a simple true/false. Complete or not. Is there a better, more suitable choice? Would this contribute to the odd behavior? Thanks! Eric